# Configure DNS Table on Sonic Wall TZ205

Tags: routing, router, dns, ip-forwarding-table

I just installed a TZ-205 on our company network and I can not seem to find where I would add to a DNS table. On our Linksys LRT224 there is a option to add a domain name and an associated IP. Does this function even exist in the Sonic Wall? I want to be able to type in "example.com" and have it point that domain name at my server IP address at home. I know I can edit the hosts file but I use my server at home for development sites I have 5 of them currently on one server so to go to every employees computer and update the hosts file will be time consuming. Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sonicwall can point to one of your own internal DNS servers (running on another device in your network), but it doesn't include a DNS server itself.  You can set your server up to do DNS and point the sonicwall at it, then all DHCP clients will use that server for name lookups.

If you have multiple websites and multiple employee workstations, it's worth it to set up your own DNS server.  It will save a lot of trouble, especially as you grow.

Comment: Jim's right on the money here.